# Need to show bootstrap model popup which is in different page on click anchor tag from angular controller

Tags: angularjs, anchor, bootstrap-modal, ascx

I need to show the bootstrap model popup which is in different page when click the anchor tag from angular controller the pop up shoul show.
   I have anchor tag in one.aspx

```
  <a id="fspstart" href="../Student/FspStartNotification.aspx" data-toggle-type="modal" data-target="#modalFSP"></a>
```

I have model popup in yes.ascx

```
   <div id="modalFSP" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Congratulations!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p><strong>Final Study Plan is available</strong></p>
            <p>Cllick here to start your Final Study Plan.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnStartFsp" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Start Final Study Plan" Style="font-size: medium; text-align: center"
                            OnClick="btnStartFsp_click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Close" Style="font-size: medium; text-align: center"
                            CssClass="cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxMessage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblchkbox" runat="server" Text="Do not show this again." Style="font-size: smaller"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>--%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Click event triggered from one.controller

```
    $('#fspstart').click();
```

but,Pop is not showing can you please help me out this where am wrong

Thanks

Comment: But where any angular code? I don't see any `ng-controller`

Comment: Controller will be there i was included only the model pop code